# Can't insert encrypted password in database using bcryptpasswordencoder in java

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring security in spring boot. I want user password should be encrypted and insert into database through controller. But I got this error

> Data too long for column 'password' at row 1

Here is WebSecurityConfig class

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from users where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from authorities where username=?")
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Here is Controller class

```
....
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
...
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitMemberForm(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        viewPage = "membership";
        return viewPage;
    }

    String userPassword = user.getPassword();

    String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(userPassword);

    Authority authority = new Authority(user.getUsername(),"ROLE_USER");

    user.setPassword(encodedPassword);

    user.setAuthority(authority);

    userDaoServiceImpl.createUser(user);
    viewPage = "membership";
    return viewPage;
}
```

[image]
I used hibernate.
How can fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be a problem with your database column's length. Could you post your database table as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring security uses $2a$ BCrypt which generates a password string that is 60 characters in legnth. Example: `$2a$10$IvpDzjQ3RhFvIECF7r2muOlLsDFywkyGJNEg1q6OudgK9.2vkubfW`
so ensure your password column is `char(60)` or `varchar(60)` at least